# MSBuild ignores project dependency order on new machine

Tags: .net, msbuild

Hi I have a solution which is compiled with a custom msbuild file.

Recently I have changed my machine from a Windows 7 machine to a new Windows 8.1 machine.

when running msbuild on the new machine it fails to build the solution, apparently because it is ignoring dependent projects that should be built ahead of other projects. This does not happen with the same set of files on my old machine.

- Both are running MSBuild 12.0.21005.1
- Both have VS 2012 and 2013 installed
- The patch numbers of .NET Framwork v4 are within a few build numbers of each other, with both on 4.0.30319.xxxx

It's driving me mad - the whole point of the new machine was to build this solution faster :)

Could anyone suggest sensible steps to resolve or at least diagnose this issue?

UPDATE: It appears to that msbuild thinks that there are no changes. I'm getting messages such as `Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.` I can't seem to convince it otherwise. The process runs Clean, then Build, so how could it not build the project?

Comment: The parallel build feature is the common issue.  You'll get more builds to run in parallel with a machine that has more cores.  With the non-zero odds that this makes the build fail because a project is being built too soon and it has a dependency on the build output of another project that isn't completed yet.  In other words, when the project dependencies were never set correctly in the first place but you just never noticed it before.

Comment: we've been parallel building for 8 months. It's not something that has changed. Also to be specific, I have also tried without /m on my build, so it is compiling in series and still fails.

Comment: The only possible way you are going to get help is when you post the "custom msbuild file" as well as build log you get out of msbuild with the output verbosity set to "diagnostic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much hunting I have the answer.

Firstly - it does not appear to have anything to do with skipping due to files being up-to-date.

by outputting the results of the build to text file I was able to hunt down a couple of lines that did not exist when building on my old machine including this warning:

```
(ResolveAssemblyReferences target) -> 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1635,5): warning MSB3274: The primary reference "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". [C:\workspaces\git\soln\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.Workflows\Orchard.Workflows.csproj]
```

We had previously updated our main web project to target .NET Framework 4.5, but some of the projects within the solution had been left on version 4.0. This worked fine on my old machine (the ones left on 4.0 should not have had references to anything built against 4.5), but clearly had problems on the new one.

On a hunch I upgraded all my projects within the solution (all 119) using this awesome tool http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/47bded90-80d8-42af-bc35-4736fdd8cd13 , after which build succeeds.

I should be clear in pointing out

1. The codebase was exactly the same on both machines
2. We never had a problem that required upgrading the target versions of the additional projects before, just on this single machine
3. The versions of msbuild and .NET frameworks are to all inspection, identical

Anyway - I hope someone reads this and gets to the root of their problem faster than I did!

Answer (score 0):

- Command prompt is your best friend for debugging MSBuild. More specifically, the `Developer Command Prompt for VS2012\2013`.
- Verify the build machine is clean from any previous builds binaries. Your build script should clean its workspace before compilation (unless its being handled by a build server). If using TFS, run [`tfpt`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35775) `treeclean`.
- Run the build with diagnostic log - `msbuild build.proj /flp:Verbosity=diagnostic;LogFile=build.log`
- Run the build without concurrency - `/m:1`. With multiple processors, concurrent processes might fail complex builds when the `/m` switch is active.
- Verify the correct MSBuild image is executed. Force full path (`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`).

Comment: I'm using the dev command prompt. The issue occurs even when getting the repo to a new machine (I deleted the entire thing and replaced more than once. It works on other machines, just not this one.

I will try the very specific /m:1, though I thought that without /m it would only compile one 1 core anyway